# ruby accessing value in hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a ruby array called activities with the following data:

```
   {
    "activity"=>
      {
        "data"=>{}, 
        "name"=>"password_update", 
        "created_at"=>"2015-04-13T06:22:44Z"}
      } 

   {
    "activity"=>
      {
        "data"=>{}, 
        "name"=>"password_update", 
        "created_at"=>"2015-04-13T06:22:44Z"
      }
   }
```

How do I go about extracting only the values of the name key?

I want to extract the "password_update" values for each of the activities... if that makes sense?

Answer (score 4):

The "array" as you say, its not valid at all...it looks like a hash structure, with same named-keys! (hash can contain only one unique key and value for it otherwise the value for the key is overrided... We can assume you have sth like this:

```
activities = [
  {
    "activity"=>
      {
        "data"=>{}, 
        "name"=>"password_update_1", 
        "created_at"=>"2015-04-13T06:22:44Z"}
      }
   },
   {
    "activity"=>
      {
        "data"=>{}, 
        "name"=>"password_update_2", 
        "created_at"=>"2015-04-13T06:22:44Z"
      }
   }]
```

This looks like an array of Hashes, now you want to get "name" from each object, you can simple use map function (create an array from block results) and hash [] accessors ..

```
names = activites.map { |v| v['activity']['name'] }
# The result:
# names = [ 'password_update_1', 'password_update_2' ]
```